# Lisp quicksort code

Tags: lisp, quick-sort, common-lisp

I would really appreciate it if someone could review my quicksort implementation.  Additionally, I generated my list dynamically and wrote a couple of tests.  Of course, I realize that the tests are not complete, but I decided to stop where I was and see if I could get some feedback.

```
(defun categorize_list(pivot thelist less more)
    (let ((comparee (car thelist)) (therest (cdr thelist)))
      (if (null thelist)
            (list less more)
        (if (< comparee pivot)
          (categorize_list pivot therest (append less (list comparee)) more)
          (categorize_list pivot therest less (append more (list comparee)))
        )
        )
      )
  )

(defun quicksort(thelist)
  (if (null thelist)
    ()
      (let (
            (pivot (car thelist))
            (therest (cdr thelist))
        )
        (let ((categorized_list (categorize_list pivot therest () ())))

            (append (quicksort (nth 0 categorized_list)) (list pivot) (quicksort (nth 1 categorized_list)))
        )
        )
      )
  )


(defun make_list(thelist remaininglength)
  (if (eq remaininglength 0)
    thelist
    (make_list (append (list (random 25)) thelist) (- remaininglength 1))
  )
  )

(defun should_be_least_to_greatest(thelist)
  (if (< (length thelist) 2)
       nil 
      (if (<= (nth 0 thelist) (nth 1 thelist))
        (should_be_least_to_greatest (cdr thelist))
        (error "Out of order: ~d !< ~d ~%" (nth 0 thelist) (nth 1 thelist))
        )
      )
  )

(defun test_should_become_in_order(thelist)
  (let ((sortedList (quicksort thelist)))
    (format t "IN: ~a ~% SD: ~a ~% Testing sort.~%" thelist sortedList)
    (should_be_least_to_greatest sortedList)
    )
  )

(defun test_should_maintain_length(thelist)
  (if (not (eql (length thelist) (length (quicksort thelist))))
    (error "The sorted list is a different length than the original list! ~%")
    )
  )

(let ((thelist (make_list () 10)))
    (test_should_become_in_order thelist)
    (test_should_maintain_length thelist)
)
```

Comment: Asymptotically, this isn't a quicksort... appending lists the way you do it makes it more expensive than the textbook version. This also conses a lot of memory. Quicksort is best suited for in-place updates of arrays with O(1) random access cost, it's not so great for lists. I think most Lisp implementations use mergesort for Lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what the policy is about where/how to put subsequent code reviews, since the Stackexchange system doesn't really seem well-suited to their threadlike nature.  Anyway, here goes.

```
(let ((pivot (car the-list)) (the-rest (cdr the-list)))
  (let ((categorized-list (categorize-list pivot the-rest () ())))
```

Look up `LET*`.

```
(let ((the-list ()))
    (loop for l from 1 to length do (setq the-list (append the-list (list (random 25))))) the-list))
```

This seems pretty awkward.  It's just:

```
(loop for l from 1 to length collect (random 25))
```

And here:

```
(loop for l from 0 to (- (length the-list) 2) do
  (unless (<= (nth l the-list) (nth (+ l 1) the-list)) (error "Out of order: ~d < ~d ~%" (nth l the-list) (nth (+ l 1) the-list)))))
```

Every call to `LENGTH` or `NTH` has to walk the linked list.  You don't want to do that in a loop.  (I think you should not often need `NTH` with lists, and almost never in a loop.)

```
(loop for p on the-list while (second p)
      when (< (second p) (first p))
      do (error "Out of order: ~d < ~d~%" (second p) (first p)))
```

If you're going to be writing Common Lisp code, it pays to learn the `LOOP` DSL (or `ITERATE`, its spiritual successor).

Other random things:

- Your code has gotten a lot ... wider.  While I appreciate taking fewer lines, there's a limit.  I don't often see multiple `LET` bindings on one line, for example.
- You sometimes still leave out the space before a paren, like `list(pivot`, which looks funny to me.

Answer (score 8):

Your formatting is weird.  It's going to be a lot easier for other programmers to read your code if you use a more standard style.  For example, you have lots of lines with nothing but a hanging parenthesis.  Your functions have no docstrings.  Sometimes you `use_underscores` and sometimes you use `compoundwords` but the Lisp style is `hypenated-words`.  Your indentation is inconsistent: learn the command in your text editor to indent your source code for you, and use it.

Instead of:

```
(if (not (eql (length thelist) (length (quicksort thelist))))
```

Using EQL for numbers seems odd.  I think = would be preferred.  An IF with only one branch is strange, too: WHEN or UNLESS tends to be preferred.  Thus:

```
(unless (= (length thelist) (length (quicksort thelist)))
```

In another place, you do a comparison with:

```
(eq remaininglength 0)
```

The behavior of EQ with integers is undefined.  You can use = or in this case:

```
(zerop remaininglength)
```

You're using recursion a lot even when it's not needed, e.g., in `make_list` and `should_be_least_to_greatest`.  Common Lisp doesn't require tail-call optimization, and it's not generally common style.  LOOP (or ITERATE) would probably be simpler and more efficient here.

You walk a list applying `<=`.  Lisp's `<=` already takes any number of arguments, so if you don't need to know the specific elements which are out of order, you can just apply it once.

Answer (score 2):

You have several negative conditionals, which is a bad idea in any language.

```
(if (null thelist)
   ()
```

I'd change it to:

```
(defun quicksort(thelist)
   (unless (null thelist)
      ; Sort list
   ) ; Pardon the dangling ), but there's a comment on the last line
```

Comment: That doesn't bother me as much: it's making the "return an empty list" case clear.